# C# Strange Incremental bug

Tags: c#, xna

Hi all I have a small problem but for me, is a big problem.

First, I have a class called `NPC`

```
public void Update()
              {

                  if (m_iMoveX != 0 || m_iMoveY != 0)
                      m_iFrame = (m_iFrame + 1) % 16;
                  else
                      m_iFrame = 0;

                  if (m_iPause > 0)
                      --m_iPause;

                  if (m_iMoveX > 0)
                  {
                      m_iPosX += 2;
                      m_iMoveX -= 2;
                  }

                  if (m_iMoveX < 0)
                  {
                      m_iPosX -= 2;
                      m_iMoveX += 2;
                  }

                  if (m_iMoveY > 0)
                  {
                      m_iPosY += 2;
                      m_iMoveY -= 2;
                  }

                  if (m_iMoveY < 0)
                  {
                      m_iPosY -= 2;
                      m_iMoveY += 2;
                  }
              }
```

Description.
`m_iMove` are a stored movement first to walk
`m_iPos` are a real coordinates for NPC.

when I make a npc walk, I set on `m_iMove + 32`.
in update, `iPos` increments and `iMove` decrement.
if `iMove` are 0 the movemente are completed.

The NPC walk on grid 32x32 pixel.

Now I think work fine, but see this screenshoot

[image: Look Title Caption]

`iMove` are equal to 0. Actually No movement.
`iPos` are 96, it's a NPC Coords.

when I increment movement

```
   pl.m_iMoveY += 32;  //Increments iMove for the movement                     

     pl.m_npcDirection = NPCDirection.Dowm; //Setup the face
     if (pl.m_iMoveY > 32)  //if i press KeyDown and iMove have a value > of 32
     pl.m_iMoveY = 32; //Force to execute 32 pixel movement
```

See this screen

[image: Look Title Caption]

Now the NPC Coords are 132 for what?

No have idea for this bug.
I increments 32 pixel for the movement.

96 + 32 = 128 but I see 132

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your `if (m_iMoveY < 0)` and the similar checks. The conditional code is executing more times than necessary. You will have to adjust the condition.

`m_iPosY += 2;` is obviously executing twice more than necessary. Put a breakpoint on that line and observe when it is being hit. Especially watch out for when the m_iPosY is greater than what you expect it to be - at the point of time inspect the value in the other variables.